# How to set a reference range of values across variables in R dataset? Where sample didn't use full range of responses

Tags: r, psych

Working with data from a survey where all questions could be answered on a 1-5 scale. However, the full range of responses was not utilised for all the questions in my survey. My concern is that R will recognise the max as 4 for some variables where it should, like the other variables, be a max of 5. I wondered if code exists to 'tell' R that the range should be 1-5 across all columns of my dataset without skewing those columns where 4 currently appears to be the 'max'.

I'm working with a df that looks like so (rough example of the columns- not exactly representative):

```
ec1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5)
ec2 <- c(1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1)
ec3 <- c(3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 5)
ec4 <- c(5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4)
ec5 <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3)
```

In the case above, some columns (`ec2` & `ec5`) range 1-4, while most range 1-5. I know `scale()` exists, but as far as I understand, this is not the right solution for what I need.

Apologies if this isn't the issue I think it is -  I'm still somewhat of a beginner and have melted my brain with R recently. Massively appreciate any advice/solutions given.

I've come across some solutions using `ref_lvl()` for factor variables (working with numeric), but do not have the experience to know whether this will suit what I need it for, and if factors will be suitable going forward for the analyses I will do (hierarchal cluster, EFA, within-subjects ANOVA).

[Bit of a side note: I'm trying to conduct a factor analysis with the data, and I'm encountering an error with the `psych::polychoric()` package. I think this variability in min/max values might be causing it. The error is pasted below, if anyone can confirm whether I'm right, then I would be grateful ("`ec`" is the name of the df containing the columns). Haven't had much luck googling it:

```
ec_poly <- polychoric(ec)
```

`Error in if (any(lower > upper)) stop("lower>upper integration limits") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`]

Comment: Try `min(df):max(df)` to get a range over the whole data frame.

Comment: If these are survey results and you know the max, can you not just divide all the values by 5?

Comment: @AndreWildberg thank you, but I already found the max/min values. I poorly worded my question- I realised later that my question was more about how R treats numerical data (as I was concerned it would treat it similarly to factors). I posted a better-phrased question elsewhere and got my answer.